# Running xcode iOS simulator build

Tags: ios, facebook, simulator

I developed an iOS app with Facebook integration. I need to send an iOS simulator build for Facebook to review how the Facebook integration works on my app.

The link provides the instructions on how to create the iOS Simulator build.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/

The said link provides code that creates the iOS simulator build

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator{version}
```

What I wanted to do is to run the app iOS Simulator Build. I want to test if iOS simulator build works.

I searched and found this:

[Launch an iOS app in the simulator without XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364647/launch-an-ios-app-in-the-simulator-without-xcode)

which asked me to use this code to run the iOS simulator build.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication ${PROJECT}/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/<yourapp>.app/<yourapp>
```

Yes, the iOS simulator runs however it does not launch my app.

How should I run the iOS simulator build on the simulator? Need help on this. Thanks!

**Addition Note:
I am using Xcode 5.1.1**

Comment: its work for me, Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24354660/3257273) and follow the steps.

Answer (score 7):

I had success using [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim).   Then run with `ios-sim launch <yourproject>.app`

Comment: This should be the right answer. If you're using brew, it's as easy as doing `brew install ios-sim` and then `ios-sim launch <your-app>.app`.

Answer (score 2):

Update instructions for Xcode 6.x and later using simctl:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /path/to/your/built/simulator.app
xcrun simctl launch booted com.your.app.identifier
```