# Building and launching app in Simulator from terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, scripting, simulator, xctool

I wanted to build and launch my iOS app using a shell script and not Xcode. My question is the similar to this question: [How to launch an iOS app in the simulator without XCode rebuilding the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364647/how-to-launch-an-ios-app-in-the-simulator-without-xcode-rebuilding-the-app), which was asked in 2012.

It says that the IPA file created in build directory within the project directory can be used. I could not find a build directory inside my project folder. Also, I want to build the app from a script.

What is the most latest way of building and running an app on simulator using terminal commands?

**Edit:**

I built the app from command line:

```
xcrun xcodebuild \
  -scheme UITestingTutorial \
  -project UITestingTutorial.xcodeproj \
  -configuration Debug \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=13.6' \
  -derivedDataPath \
  build
```

But how do I launch it now?

Answer (score 3):

Running this script inside your project directory will launch the app programmatically.

```
xcrun xcodebuild \
-scheme UITestingTutorial \
-project UITestingTutorial.xcodeproj \
-configuration Debug \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=13.6' \
-derivedDataPath \
build

open -a "Simulator"

# This simulator id has been manually found
# by running 'xcrun simctl list' and searching
# for iPhone 11 under iOS 13.6 under Devices 
# A script can be written to automatically find this.
xcrun instruments -w 3100E7BC-0B95-4B3E-B0DC-8743FFCB731A
xcrun simctl install 3100E7BC-0B95-4B3E-B0DC-8743FFCB731A ./build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UITestingTutorial.app (http://uitestingtutorial.app/)
xcrun simctl launch 3100E7BC-0B95-4B3E-B0DC-8743FFCB731A com.codepro.UITestingTutorial
```

You can refer to [Launch apps in iOS Simulator using Terminal](https://medium.com/@tci/launch-apps-in-ios-simulator-using-terminal-5f21d60b7151) for more details. Please note the `xctool` is deprecated.